# Using X-Accel-Redirect in Nginx ingress ( kubernetes)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress

Anyone knows how to use X-Accel-Redirect in Nginx ingress ( kubernetes), I need to redirect from location (/download-file/) to an internal folder in my app to return a file.

I really Appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533514/move-x-accel-redirect-pattern-for-protected-static-in-kubernetes-setup ?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it didn't help, I want to redirect and return the files from one service.

Comment: Did you also take a look https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/ https://kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/ https://github.com/michaelklishin/nginx-x-accel-redirect-example-application/blob/master/config/nginx.config.sample ?